# How to add a linked user name in a comment that will alert user that he has a mention?

Tags: support, comments

I am relatively new to this site. I notice that some comments in threads have  responses to particular users where the username is a link that alerts them of a comment directed at them, How can I do this with the following cases:

1. Single word user name. (Example: JohnDoe, is it @JohnDoe ?)
2. Double word user name. (Example: John Doubleday is it @John Doubleday ?)

One more question. Are user names case sensitive. In other words do the names need to be case sensitive?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255387/how-do-i-reference-a-user-with-a-space-in-their-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are ignored in comment mentions. For your specific scenarios:

1. `@JohnDoe`
2. `@JohnDoubleday`

Technically, though you only need the first three characters. So, for either of those, depending on who is "involved" with the post, `@joh` will work.

Further, if you use the auto-complete, you'll note that there are no spaces in the name. They're also not case-sensitive.

There are some rules about who can be contacted, though. You can't "ping" just anyone. It has to be a person who left a comment or who edited the post. The post author (and the Asker, if different) are always notified, so there's no need for the @notification. (And, in a lot of cases, you won't be able to add it.)

See also: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)